# How to do MouseDown in XAML in Windows 8 application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to trigger the event of MouseDown or MouseRightButtonDown on the Button control. But it doesn't allow me to have it. It does provide me with Click, but I want to handle the MouseDown event on button.

I'm using the following code:

```
<Button Width="230" Margin="130, -57, 0, 0" Background="Green" 
                    BorderBrush="DarkGreen" Click="Button_Click">=</Button>
```

What might be an alternate around to handle the MouseDown event?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Windows 8 apps aren't guaranteed to have the use of a mouse as an input device.  Windows 8 is designed to run on touchscreens as well.  Therefore the concept of MouseDown was deprecated.
Why does Click not serve your needs?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button.aspx#events

PointerPressed might be what you are looking for?

Comment: The OP is programming in WPF, and not Windows Store apps.

Comment: Because I need to change the Style of the button on the `MouseDown` event. You're right, I am well aware of this problem. I was just hoping for some alternate method to hold this. However, I have tried `Pointer` related events too. They don't work either. I want something like `MouseDown` to change the Style of the button. That is my intent.

Comment: @WaltRitscher He said XAML in the title, not WPF.

Comment: AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: I'm sorry to hear they aren't working for you.  Strangely though, I am pretty sure I have been able to do exactly what I think you are trying to do using `Pointer` events.  Somewhat unhelpfully, I can't really say much more than that without seeing what you are trying to do.  `PointerPressed` should in theory be triggered at the same time as `MouseDown` would be triggered if it existed, so you should be able to use it to do the same things.  I think your problem might be with how you are trying to change the style, not with the event you are using.

Comment: @Noodles.  True, but there is also a WPF tag on the post.  That's where I got the idea it was a WPF related question.